# Bitlocker shut down my computer when i try to enter password

Tags: windows, passwords, shutdown

i have problem with bitlocker,

when computer start, and blue screen show's up with password form,

my computer shut down after couple of seconds, i can't finish type my password.

Anyone have similar issue ?

Sometimes i manage to eneter whole password, and everything is ok, system is load, everything is stable..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a elevated command prompt (hit windows key, type cmd, right-click cmd and click on "Run as administrator") and type:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} bootshutdowndisabled 1
```

Hit enter, "The operation completed successfully."

Reboot and wait...